# Detecting `package_name::function_name()` with static code analysis

Tags: r, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am trying to dive into the internals of static code analysis packages like `codetools` and `CodeDepends`, and my immediate goal is to understand how to detect function calls written as `package_name::function_name()` or `package_name:::function_name()`. I would have liked to just use `findGlobals()` from `codetools`, but this is not so simple.

Example function to analyze:

```
f <- function(n){
  tmp <- digest::digest(n)
  stats::rnorm(n)
}
```

Desired functionality:

```
analyze_function(f)
## [1] "digest::digest" "stats::rnorm"
```

Attempt with `codetools`:

```
library(codetools)
f = function(n) stats::rnorm(n)
findGlobals(f, merge = FALSE)
## $functions
## [1] "::"
## 
## $variables
## character(0)
```

`CodeDepends` comes closer, but I am not sure I can always use the output to match functions to packages. I am looking for an automatic rule that connects `rnorm()` to `stats` and `digest()` to `digest`.

```
library(CodeDepends)
getInputs(body(f)
## An object of class "ScriptNodeInfo"
## Slot "files":
## character(0)
## 
## Slot "strings":
## character(0)
## 
## Slot "libraries":
## [1] "digest" "stats" 
## 
## Slot "inputs":
## [1] "n"
## 
## Slot "outputs":
## [1] "tmp"
## 
## Slot "updates":
## character(0)
## 
## Slot "functions":
##      {     :: digest  rnorm 
##     NA     NA     NA     NA 
## 
## Slot "removes":
## character(0)
## 
## Slot "nsevalVars":
## character(0)
## 
## Slot "sideEffects":
## character(0)
## 
## Slot "code":
## {
##     tmp <- digest::digest(n)
##     stats::rnorm(n)
## }
```

**EDIT** To be fair to `CodeDepends`, there is so much customizability and power for those who understand the internals. At the moment, I am just trying to wrap my head around collectors, handlers, walkers, etc. Apparently, it is possible to modify the standard `::` collector to make special note of each namespaced call. For now, here is a naive attempt at something similar.

```
col <- inputCollector(`::` = function(e, collector, ...){
  collector$call(paste0(e[[2]], "::", e[[3]]))
})
getInputs(quote(stats::rnorm(x)), collector = col)@functions
Browse[1]> getInputs(quote(stats::rnorm(x)), collector = col)@functions
stats::rnorm        rnorm 
          NA           NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract namespaced functions from a function, try something like this

```
find_ns_functions <- function(f, found=c()) {
    if( is.function(f) ) {
        # function, begin search on body
        return(find_ns_functions(body(f), found))
    } else if (is.call(f) && deparse(f[[1]]) %in% c("::", ":::")) {
        found <- c(found, deparse(f))
    } else if (is.recursive(f)) {
        # compound object, iterate through sub-parts
        v <- lapply(as.list(f), find_ns_functions, found)
        found <- unique( c(found, unlist(v) ))        
    }
    found
}
```

And we can test with

```
f <- function(n){
  tmp <- digest::digest(n)
  stats::rnorm(n)
}

find_ns_functions(f)
# [1] "digest::digest" "stats::rnorm"
```

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I needed to read in order to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this was possible with CodeDepends previously, but a bit harder than it should have been. I've just committed version 0.5-4 to github, which now makes this really "easy". Essentially you just need to modify the default colonshandlers ("::" and/or ":::") as follows:

```
library(CodeDepends) # version >= 0.5-4
handler = function(e, collector, ..., iscall = FALSE) {
    collector$library(asVarName(e[[2]]))
    ## :: or ::: name, remove if you don't want to count those as functions called
    collector$call(asVarName(e[[1]])) 
    if(iscall)
        collector$call(deparse((e))) #whole expr ie stats::norm
    else
        collector$vars(deparse((e)), input=TRUE) #whole expr ie stats::norm
}

getInputs(quote(stats::rnorm(x,y,z)), collector = inputCollector("::" = handler))
getInputs(quote(lapply( 1:10, stats::rnorm)), collector = inputCollector("::" = handler))
```

The first getInputs call above gives the result:

```
An object of class "ScriptNodeInfo"
Slot "files":
character(0)

Slot "strings":
character(0)

Slot "libraries":
[1] "stats"

Slot "inputs":
[1] "x" "y" "z"

Slot "outputs":
character(0)

Slot "updates":
character(0)

Slot "functions":
          :: stats::rnorm 
          NA           NA 

Slot "removes":
character(0)

Slot "nsevalVars":
character(0)

Slot "sideEffects":
character(0)

Slot "code":
stats::rnorm(x, y, z)
```

As, I believe, desired.

One thing to note here is the iscall argument I've added to the colons handler. The default handler and applyhandlerfactory now have special logic so that when they invoke one of the colons handlers in a situation where it is a function being called, that is set to TRUE.

I haven't done extensive testing yet of what will happen when "stats::rnorm" appears in lieu of symbols, particularly in the inputs slot when calculating dependencies, but I'm hopeful that should all continue to work as well. If it doesn't let me know.

~G

Comment: Excellent! This will help me integrate CodeDepends into future projects.